# When using my class using a getter, it loses its value and I don't understand why

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem where my getter and setter returns a null value. I've read about it here on the forum and I found people saying that I had instantiated my class and reset the values, but I don't find the error. After adding new service, my getter and setter loses its value and I don't understand why

My class

```
public class ServicosS implements Serializable {

private String nome;
private String preco;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getPreco() {
    return preco;
}

public void setPreco(String preco) {
    this.preco = preco;
}
```

}

My Fragment

```
public class ServicosFragment extends Fragment {

private FloatingActionButton fab;
private List<ServicosS> listaServicos;
private ServicosAdapter servicosAdapter;
private RecyclerView Rv_servicos;
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

public ServicosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_servicos, container, false);

    Rv_servicos = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_servicos);
    listaServicos = new ArrayList<>();
    carregarServicos();

    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_servicos);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AdcServicosActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void carregarServicos(){

    listaServicos.clear();

    ClientesDAO clientesDAO = new ClientesDAO();

    //Configura o adapter
    servicosAdapter = new ServicosAdapter(listaServicos,getActivity());

    //Configurar o RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    Rv_servicos.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    Rv_servicos.setHasFixedSize(true);
    Rv_servicos.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getParentFragment().getContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
    Rv_servicos.setAdapter( servicosAdapter );

    DatabaseReference servicosRef = database.child("Servicos");

    servicosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                listaServicos.add(ds.getValue(ServicosS.class));
                Log.i("INFO","PRODUTO: "+ds.getValue(Servicos.class).getNomeS());
            }
            servicosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

My activity that adds data to the database

```
public class AdcServicosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputEditText nome_servico,preco_servico;
private Button salvarServico;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adc_servicos);

    nome_servico = findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_servico);
    preco_servico = findViewById(R.id.txt_preco_servico);
    salvarServico = findViewById(R.id.btn_salvar_servico);

    salvarServico.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nomeServico = nome_servico.getText().toString();
            String precoServico = preco_servico.getText().toString();


            if (nomeServico != null && precoServico != null){

                ServicosS servicosS = new ServicosS();
                ServicosDAO servicosDAO = new ServicosDAO();
                servicosS.setNome(nomeServico);
                servicosS.setPreco(precoServico);

                if(servicosDAO.salvar(servicosS)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Êxito ao salvar",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "ERRO ao salvar",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Complete os campos",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

my ServicesDAO

```
public class ServicosDAO implements iServicosDAO {

final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

@Override
public boolean salvar(ServicosS servicosS) {

    DatabaseReference servicoRef2 = database.child("Servicos");
    DatabaseReference servicoRef3 = servicoRef2.child(servicosS.getNome());

    servicoRef3.child("Nome").setValue(servicosS.getNome());
    servicoRef3.child("Nome_pesquisa").setValue(servicosS.getNome().toUpperCase());
    servicoRef3.child("Preco").setValue(servicosS.getPreco());



    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean deletar(ServicosS servicosS) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which object loses its value?

Comment: my getter that is present in my "ServicesS" class loses its value after I add my setter values ​​in Firebase